# Bulk network folder deletion using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Powershell noob here. What I want to basically do is delete old users H drives using a script. I have a CSV file which reads like below:-

```
Folder Path
u:\users\xxx1
u:\users\xxx2
```

and so on.

These paths sit on a nas server. I want to read the path from csv and if the folder exists delete it. I have tried a couple of things to no avail.

```
Set-Location "\\XXX-nas1\users"
$TargetFolder = Import-Csv H:\folderdeletetest.csv
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 

Remove-Item -Path $Folder.Folder -Recurse -Force
}
```

I was wondering if i can get some help . That will be highly appreciated. Cheers
Regards
WVC

---

Csv looks like below:

```
FolderPath
u:\users\xxx1
u:\users\xxx2
```

Code :

```
Set-Location "\\xxx-nas1\users"
$TargetFolder = Import-Csv c:\folderdeletetest.csv
ForEach ($folderpath in $TargetFolder) { 

    Remove-Item -Path $folderpath.Folder -Recurse -Force
}
```

Goal is to compare if a folder in csv exist on the network share. If it exist, then delete it. If its simpler to do it via text file without absolute path (i.e foldername only in the text file). I can change it to that.
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you're having?  Is it reading the file?  Iterating over its contents?  Or deleting the folders?

Comment: Hi Nate, The problem I have is I don't know how to check if the folder in the csv exists in the actual share location and delete it

Comment: The first thing I would do is make sure you correctly read the path from the csv.  In your `foreach` loop, do a `Write-Host $Folder` to make sure it's really what you think it is.  (`$Folders` has never been assigned in the code sample you list, so your problem may not be where you think it is.)  Once you've got it writing out the correct paths, then I think your `Remove-Item` call should work.

Comment: Hi Nate,Thanks I see what you saying. I have fixed that part. Now I am getting output in the below format.                      @{path=reesor}
@{path=pastor}
@{path=lagos}                                                         how do I check if the folder exist on the network share .I have set the network path location in the first line of the code. I really appreciate your help. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `test-path` if you want to test that a folder exists before trying to delete it.

And use `$folderpath.FolderPath` to access the `FolderPath` column from your csv file.

```
test-path $folderpath.FolderPath
```

But I think you could also just go ahead and do `remove-item`.  If the path doesn't exist it'll just return an error.

Comment: test-path is returning false.I possibly have issue connecting to the network share i believe. Does the set-location syntax looks ok or do i have to do someonthing else to connect to the Nas storage. I am getting below error when i run :-  @{path=Test Folder 2}
False
Remove-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\f770ec1a-06e1-45e4-861e-1b0b06111bc5.ps1:6 char:18
+ Remove-Item -Path <<<<  $path.Folder -Recurse -Force
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-Item

Comment: Personally I would avoid using `set-location` and instead use full paths everywhere.

Comment: It's really hard to make sense of code in these comments.  How about you edit your original question and put in the real code.

Comment: Edited. Please have a look. Cheers

Comment: You're referencing `$folderpath.Folder`.  It should be `$folderpath.FolderPath`.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this has answered your question, please mark it as Accepted.